# Can a 64bit vmware host be configured so that a windows server 2003 32bit client can page to ram

Tags: memory, paging, vmware, ramdisk, pagefile

I have a legacy windows 2003 R2 32 bit system (client) which has been migrated to a very large vmware 64 bit host (host) with massive ram.

Can the host be configured with a disk in ram that can be used as a page file by the client such that paging is actually to ram.

IT manages the host and I need to provide guidance (key words, links, references) to facilitate the solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Windows still likes to place the page file on the drive where the OS itself is installed i.e. the C:\ drive.  So , it is better to put the complete VMWare VMDK file itself on the ramdisk on the host. This will make your client even more performant.
Example for Hyper-V :

[image]